# Can we use enzyme mount for testing react-native redux connected(higher order) components which are written in typescript

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme, mount

To test the react-native redux connected(higher order) components,we need to use enzyme mount for accessing mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps etc...As enzyme mount api uses jsdom .Is mount supported in react-native or not?.
I went through different articles  and it was mentioned that we can use mount for testing react-native redux connected components.
In my jest setup file I have given this piece of code.

```js
    /** jest setup file **/
    import { configure } from "enzyme";
    import EnzymeAdapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
    configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });
    
    /**
     * Set up DOM in node.js environment for Enzyme to mount to
     */
    const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom"); 
    const jsdom = new JSDOM("");
    const { window } = jsdom;
    
    function copyProps(src: any, target: NodeJS.Global) {
      Object.defineProperties(target, {
        ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(src),
        ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(target)
      });
    }
    
    global.window = window;
    global.document = window.document;
    global.navigator = {
      userAgent: "node.js"
    };
    copyProps(window, global);
    
    const originalConsoleError = console.error;
    console.error = (message: string) => {
      if (message.startsWith("Warning:")) {
        return;
      }
    
      originalConsoleError(message);
    };
```

If I commented originalConsoleError method.,even though test case got passed we are getting this error.

```js
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
          Warning: <Text /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
              in Text (created by Text)
              in Text (at create-icon-set.js:92)
              in Icon (created by Avatar)
              in Avatar (created by WrapperComponent)
              in WrapperComponent
```

Can we really use mount for testing react-native higherorder
components.If not, how can we test using jest and enzyme?If yes, how
to avoid these errors without suppressing it like originalConsoleError
method?